# Can anyone help me compute the mean curvature of a paraboloid?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

Given a paraboloid with the following equation

\begin{align}
z = P(x,y) = c_0 + c_1x + c_2y + c_3xy + c_4x^2 + c_5y^2,
\end{align}

how would I derive an expression for the $\textbf{mean}$ curvature $H=\tfrac{1}{2}(\kappa_1+\kappa_2)$, where $\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_2$ are the principal curvatures at the point $\big(x,y,P(x,y)\big)$? I specifically want to evaluate the mean curvature at $\big(0,0,P(0,0)\big)$.

Comment: I don't understand. The curvature at a point is whatever it is. It makes no sense to talk about the average curvature at a point, without reference to some region over which you're averaging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Mean curvature $H$ for a surface $z=P(x,y)$ satisfies

$$2H = -\nabla\cdot\left(\frac{\nabla(z-P)}{|\nabla(z-P)|}\right)$$
Can you compute this?

Comment: I didn't realise it was that straightforward! I've been reading about having to compute the first and second fundamental forms of the surface to compute curvature. Are these not necessary? If not, what context would they be required in?

Comment: Look at [this link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_curvature). The special case of a surface $z=P(x,y)$ simplifies things considerably.

Comment: Oh! I see. Thanks so much for the insight!